# Getting the list of Objects and the corresponding value in Postgres (JSON data)

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have the following JSON data which has an array of Objects PRODUCTION -> KBM -> (array of Objects)

What I am looking for is to get all the values for the Version under the KBM.

I am able to pick only any one while I am passing the 0th, 1st or 2nd Object reference like

```
SELECT (result_json-> 'PRODUCTION' -> 'KBM' -> 0 ->> 'Version') as Version_History
        from sha.assessment_info;
```

Screenshot of the structure along with the json data :

[image: JSON Data]

I don not wish to pass the 0, 1 or 2 each time. I want it in some kind of loop to handle the situation and give me all the versions in one column.

Is there any way to achieve that?

BElow is the JSON Data:

```
"{
    "PRODUCTION": {
        "KBM": [{
            "Version": "8.3.10.112.1L",
            "Last Updated": "06/05/16 11:20:57 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "8.3.8.24",
            "Last Updated": "11/06/14  1:50:07 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "8.3.0.16.10",
            "Last Updated": "11/04/14  7:11:23 PM"
        }],
        "EHR": [{
            "Version": "5.8.2.74",
            "Last Updated": "06/03/16  2:06:06 AM"
        },

        {
            "Version": "5.2.14",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:44:45 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.2.13",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:44:44 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.2.12",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:44:43 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.2.11",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:43:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.2.10",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:43:57 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.2.9",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:43:56 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.2.8",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:43:42 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.2.7",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:43:17 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.2.6",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:43:13 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.2.5",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:43:07 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.2.4",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:10:43 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.2.3",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:10:38 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.2.2",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:10:33 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.2.1",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:10:20 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.1.7",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:10:18 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.1.6",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:10:16 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.1.5",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:10:15 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.1.4",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:05:15 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.1.3",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:05:13 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.1.2",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:05:08 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.1.1",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:05:07 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.0.33",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:05:03 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.0.32",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:05:02 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.0.31",
            "Last Updated": "09/14/04  6:09:55 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.0.27",
            "Last Updated": "08/25/04  1:40:37 PM"
        }],
        "EPM": [{
            "Version": "5.8.2",
            "Last Updated": "06/03/16  1:59:56 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.8.1",
            "Last Updated": "06/03/16  1:58:22 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.8.0",
            "Last Updated": "11/04/14  4:40:15 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.7.3",
            "Last Updated": "11/04/14  4:40:01 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.7.2",
            "Last Updated": "12/28/11  1:05:20 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.7.1",
            "Last Updated": "12/28/11  1:03:03 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.6.6",
            "Last Updated": "12/28/11  1:02:41 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.6.9",
            "Last Updated": "12/28/11  1:02:08 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.6.8",
            "Last Updated": "09/02/11  3:31:22 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.6.7",
            "Last Updated": "09/02/11  3:29:40 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.6.5",
            "Last Updated": "01/03/11  1:45:01 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.6.4",
            "Last Updated": "03/27/10  5:43:36 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.6.3",
            "Last Updated": "03/24/10  5:11:44 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.6.2",
            "Last Updated": "03/23/10  8:52:27 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.6.1",
            "Last Updated": "03/23/10  8:45:40 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.5.28",
            "Last Updated": "11/30/09 10:55:47 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.5.27",
            "Last Updated": "11/30/09 10:52:32 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.5.26",
            "Last Updated": "11/30/09 10:52:01 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.5.25",
            "Last Updated": "11/30/09 10:51:49 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.5.24",
            "Last Updated": "11/30/09 10:51:28 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.5.23",
            "Last Updated": "11/30/09 10:50:58 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.5.22",
            "Last Updated": "11/30/09  8:44:55 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.5.21",
            "Last Updated": "11/30/09  8:35:03 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.5.20",
            "Last Updated": "11/30/09  8:34:58 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.5.19",
            "Last Updated": "11/30/09  8:34:54 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.5.18",
            "Last Updated": "11/30/09  8:34:49 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.5.17",
            "Last Updated": "11/30/09  8:34:45 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.5.16",
            "Last Updated": "11/30/09  8:34:42 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.5.15",
            "Last Updated": "11/30/09  8:33:32 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.5.14",
            "Last Updated": "11/30/09  8:33:25 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.5.13",
            "Last Updated": "11/30/09  8:33:22 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.5.12",
            "Last Updated": "11/30/09  8:33:20 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.5.11",
            "Last Updated": "11/30/09  8:31:32 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.5.10",
            "Last Updated": "11/30/09  8:28:26 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.5.9",
            "Last Updated": "11/30/09  8:28:22 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.5.8",
            "Last Updated": "11/30/09  8:12:12 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.5.7",
            "Last Updated": "11/30/09  8:07:02 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.5.6",
            "Last Updated": "11/30/09  8:06:58 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.5.5",
            "Last Updated": "11/30/09  7:57:33 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.5.4",
            "Last Updated": "11/30/09  7:57:30 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.5.3",
            "Last Updated": "11/30/09  7:57:27 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.5.2",
            "Last Updated": "11/30/09  7:51:27 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.5.1",
            "Last Updated": "11/30/09  7:47:54 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.5.0",
            "Last Updated": "11/30/09  7:47:50 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.4.29",
            "Last Updated": "11/30/09  7:46:46 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.4.28",
            "Last Updated": "11/30/09  7:46:15 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.4.27",
            "Last Updated": "11/25/09  9:52:17 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.4.26",
            "Last Updated": "11/25/09  9:52:14 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.4.25",
            "Last Updated": "11/25/09  9:52:10 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.4.24",
            "Last Updated": "11/25/09  9:52:07 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.4.23",
            "Last Updated": "11/25/09  9:52:01 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.4.22",
            "Last Updated": "11/25/09  9:52:00 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.4.21",
            "Last Updated": "11/25/09  9:49:05 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.4.20",
            "Last Updated": "11/25/09  9:49:03 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.4.19",
            "Last Updated": "11/25/09  9:34:12 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.4.18",
            "Last Updated": "11/25/09  9:34:09 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.4.17",
            "Last Updated": "11/25/09  9:30:50 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.4.16",
            "Last Updated": "11/25/09  9:16:44 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.4.15",
            "Last Updated": "11/25/09  9:16:41 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.4.14",
            "Last Updated": "11/25/09  9:12:30 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.4.13",
            "Last Updated": "11/25/09  9:12:25 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.4.12",
            "Last Updated": "11/25/09  9:12:22 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.4.11",
            "Last Updated": "11/25/09  9:12:19 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.4.10",
            "Last Updated": "11/25/09  9:12:17 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.4.9",
            "Last Updated": "11/25/09  9:12:14 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.4.8",
            "Last Updated": "11/25/09  9:01:55 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.4.7",
            "Last Updated": "11/25/09  9:01:52 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.4.6",
            "Last Updated": "11/25/09  9:01:50 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.4.5",
            "Last Updated": "11/25/09  9:01:47 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.4.4",
            "Last Updated": "11/25/09  8:54:54 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.4.3",
            "Last Updated": "11/25/09  8:54:50 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.4.2",
            "Last Updated": "11/25/09  8:54:47 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.4.1",
            "Last Updated": "11/25/09  8:52:32 AM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.39",
            "Last Updated": "08/21/06  3:26:33 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.38",
            "Last Updated": "06/21/06  4:41:04 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.37",
            "Last Updated": "01/23/06  3:08:06 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.36",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  5:19:37 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.35",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  5:19:27 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.34",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  5:19:20 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.33",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  5:19:16 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.32",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  5:13:55 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.31",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  5:13:54 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.30",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  5:13:51 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.29",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  5:13:50 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.28",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  5:13:48 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.27",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  5:13:46 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.26",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  5:13:39 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.25",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  5:13:37 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.24",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  5:13:34 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.23",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  5:13:22 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.22",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  5:13:21 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.21",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  5:13:19 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.20",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  5:08:25 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.19",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  5:08:20 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.18",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  5:08:18 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.17",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  5:08:17 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.16",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  5:08:16 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.15",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  5:08:14 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.14",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  5:08:12 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.13",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:46:09 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.12",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:46:04 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.11",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:46:01 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.10",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:45:57 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.9",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:45:53 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.8",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:45:51 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.7",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:45:45 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.6",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:45:40 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.5",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:45:38 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.4",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:45:34 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.3",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:45:30 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.2",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:45:24 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.3.1",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:45:05 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.2.16",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:44:47 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.2.15",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:44:46 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.2.14",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:44:45 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.2.13",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:44:44 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.2.12",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:44:43 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.2.11",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:43:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.2.10",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:43:57 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.2.9",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:43:56 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.2.8",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:43:42 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.2.7",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:43:17 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.2.6",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:43:13 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.2.5",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:43:07 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.2.4",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:10:43 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.2.3",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:10:38 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.2.2",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:10:33 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.2.1",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:10:20 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.1.7",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:10:18 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.1.6",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:10:16 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.1.5",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:10:15 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.1.4",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:05:15 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.1.3",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:05:13 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.1.2",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:05:08 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.1.1",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:05:07 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.0.33",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:05:03 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.0.32",
            "Last Updated": "12/12/05  4:05:02 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.0.31",
            "Last Updated": "09/14/04  6:09:55 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "5.0.27",
            "Last Updated": "08/25/04  1:40:37 PM"
        }],
        "DASHBOARD": [{
            "Version": "3.3.1.08",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:02:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.1.08",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:01:44 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.1.8",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:01 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.1.7",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:01 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.1.6",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:01 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.1.5",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:01 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.1.4",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:01 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.1.3",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:01 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.1.2",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:01 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.1.1",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:01 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.76",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:01 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.75",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:01 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.74",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:01 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.73",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:01 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.72",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:01 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.71",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:01 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.70",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:01 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.69",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:01 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.68",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.67",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.66",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.65",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.64",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.63",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.62",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.61",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.60",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.59",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.58",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.57",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.56",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.55",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.54",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.53",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.52",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.51",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.50",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.49",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.48",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.47",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.46",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.45",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.44",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.43",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.42",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.41",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.40",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.39",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.38",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.37",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.36",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.35",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.34",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16  1:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.33",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.32",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.31",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.30",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.29",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.28",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.27",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.26",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.25",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.24",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.23",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.22",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.21",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.20",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.19",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.18",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.17",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.16",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.15",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.14",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.13",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.12",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.11",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.10",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.9",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.8",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.7",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.6",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.5",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.4",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.3",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.2",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.3.0.1",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.2.0.20",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.2.0.19",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.2.0.18",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.2.0.17",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:59 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.2.0.16",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:58 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.2.0.15",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:58 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.2.0.14",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:58 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.2.0.13",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:58 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.2.0.12",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:58 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.2.0.11",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:58 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.2.0.10",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:58 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.2.0.9",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:58 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.2.0.8",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:58 PM"
        },
        {
            "Version": "3.2.0.7",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:59:58 PM"
        },

        {
            "Version": "3.3.1.1",
            "Last Updated": "08/05/16 12:54:54 PM"
        }]
    }

    }
"
```

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : I have modified my question and given the JSON data also now. Could you please help me on this? I am stuck badly. I am not getting any idea how to loop on that object and get all the values in one shot

Comment: Which Postgres version are you really using? Can't be 9.3 and 9.4 at the same time

Comment: I am using 9.4 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract all array elements using `jsonb_array_elements` and then get the version attribute from the resulting JSONs:

```
select t ->> 'Version'
from assessment_info, json_array_elements(result_json -> 'PRODUCTION' -> 'KBM') as t(d)
```

Comment: Thanks A lot buddy. Its for me json_array_elements. Anyways, that did my job well.

Comment: One more thing. I didn't understand the t(d) part. Could you elaborate a little on that . Even I was using some command but if the declaration is missing then its not taking.

Comment: It's a table alias for the result of the function: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-SUBQUERIES

Comment: got it .. I did this finally. `Select (json_array_elements(result_json -> 'PRODUCTION' -> 'KBM')->>'Version')as Version_History , (json_array_elements(result_json -> 'PRODUCTION' -> 'KBM')->>'Last Updated')as Last_Updated from sha.assessment_info;`